# What is the Sobolev Lemma?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

In the paper I am reading the authors state that $|\nabla u|_\infty$ can be replaced by $|u|_3$ using the Sobolev Lemma. I am trying to find this lemma but its turned out to be very difficult.

The context is the following:

- a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$
- $|\cdot|_s$ denotes the Sobolev norm of the space $W^{s,2}(\Omega)=H^2(\Omega)$ and $|\cdot|_\infty$ the norm in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$
- $u$ is a vector valued function (the velocity of a fluid)

This has to be one of the many imbedding theorems which should give
$$|\nabla u|_\infty \leq C \: |u|_3$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on $\Omega$ alone I suppose.

I'd appreciate if you can give me a reference as well. ThX!

Comment: Your function $u$ belongs to what space?

Comment: Should be in $W^{1,\infty}$ I suppose.

Comment: I think I might have found the relevant theorem after all. It's Corollary 9.13 in Brezis's book FA, SS and PDEs (page 284). It's strange that I could not find it in Adams being that its a more thorough account of Sobolev's Spaces.

Comment: Well, not really I just realized that this result if for the whole of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: I do not understand you notation. What is $s$? and if $u$ is only in $W^{1,\infty}$ how can you estimare the norm $|u|_3$?

Comment: $s$ is how many derivatives you are considering. I don't know how you do this...

Comment: Ok, so you are supposing that $u\in W^{3,2}$?

Comment: Yes, I guess so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that your function $u$ belongs to $W^{3,2}(\Omega)$. We have the following result that can be found in any good book of Sobolev spaces (for example in [Leoni's](http://www.hotfrog.com.br/Empresas/CICLO-CHAVES/ANILLIA-OU-ALTERE-PINTADO-26605) book or even in [Brezi's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) book, but in the later you have to iterate the estimates that he find only to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$).

If $\Omega$ is a bounded regular domain, $p\geq 1$, $k>\frac{n}{p}$ then $$W^{k,p}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^m(\overline{\Omega}),\ \forall\ 0\leq m<k-\frac{n}{p}$$

In your case: $p=2$, $n=3$ and $k=3$, then $m\in[0,3/2]$, which implies your result.

Comment: Thank you! So how does this imply my result exactly. I know that with $m=1$, $\nabla u$ is continuous and therefore bounded in the compact set $\bar{\Omega}$. What norm do you define on $C^m(\bar{\Omega})$? Something like $||u|| = \max_{x \in \bar{\Omega}}{|u|} + \max_{x \in \bar{\Omega}}{|\nabla u|}$

Comment: Yes, thi norm is good.